# NextJS redirects not redirecting urls after define in next.config.js file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, module.exports

I tried to define redirects in my NextJS app.
but it is not working.

This is how I tried to do it in my next.config.js file:

```
const withImages = require('next-images')
const withPlugins = require("next-compose-plugins");
const optimizedImages = require("next-optimized-images");

module.exports = withPlugins(
    [
        [optimizedImages, {
            inlineImageLimit: 512
        }]
    ],
    {
        async redirects() {
            return [
                {
                    source: "/sales/guest/form",
                    destination: "/",
                    permanent: true
                }
            ]
        },
        env:{
            testEnvVar: 'vallll'
        }
    }
);
```

This is the documentation of how to do it:
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects

Comment: Have you find a way to make it work ?

Comment: It looks like this is a bug / conflict with next-images and next-optimized-images. I've filed an issue here: https://github.com/twopluszero/next-images/issues/69

Comment: As noted below by @Matt, it doesn't appear that the redirects hot-reload, so you'll have to manually bounce your nextjs server.

Answer (score 11):

For redirects and rewrites to work properly in NextJs, you also need to ensure one more thing:

If you are using `trailingSlash: true` then your source paths must end with a slash.

```
{
    source: '/old/:id/',  // Notice the slash at the end
    destination: '/new/:id',
},
```

Any other plugins or configurations that interfere with routing also need to be taken into account.

Comment: And, in my case, the inverse applied: you should ensure that your URLs don't end in a trailing slash (if you haven't configured it to handle it this way)

Answer (score 5):

you can add all you imports and also `const` definitions to first `array` parameter like this

```js
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const css = require('@zeit/next-css');
const less = require('@zeit/next-less');

const nextConfig = {
  target: 'serverless',
  webpack(config, { isServer, webpack }) {
   // al your config
      
    return config;
  },
};

const redirects = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/old/blogs/:slug*',
        destination: 'whatever your new rewrite url',
        permanent: true,
      },
    ];
  },
};
module.exports = withPlugins(
  [
    [css],
    [less],
    [redirects], // you can directly drop your redirect rules here 
  ],
  nextConfig
);
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I tried to redirect to external link. I had `trailingSlash: true` and I ended my source path with slash.

It didn't work because I use `Link` component from `next/link`

I changed it to normal `a` tag and it worked.

Before:

```html
<Link href="/some-path" passHref>
  <a>
   to external
  </a>
</Link>
```

After:

```
{/* eslint-disable-next-line @next/next/no-html-link-for-pages */}
<a href="/some-path">
  to external
</a>
```

> You need to disable eslint rule `@next/next/no-html-link-for-pages` so it won't raise error while building

in next.config.js file:

```js
module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
  reactStrictMode: true,
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/some-path",
        destination: "https://example.com",
        permanent: true,
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What NextJS Version are you on? Redirects are supported from 9.5 upwards

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has this problem, try restarting the server. The config file will be reloaded then.

Answer (score 0):

#### **For anyone struggling with this problem, here is a solution**

What the questioner has done in `next.config.js` is correct and it is stated in the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects) as you will be needing the redirects key to allow incoming traffic to be passed on to the other destination.

So their incoming traffic for the source path is `source: "/sales/guest/form"`

And prehaps use an if condition if met to redirect to the homepage as they have it in `next.config.js`, `destination: "/"`

To complete this you will have to go to the `Form` page in the pages directory, and address this redirects from the `Form` page

and import the redirects like below

So basically inside the `FORM file` inside pages assuming the path through the directories are as:

/sales/guest/form

```
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';

const Form = () => {

// prehaps have a condition to tell it when to redirect so:

    // this condition is met whatever
    if (1 === 1) {
        redirect("/");
    }

    // .. rest of the code

}


export default Form;
```